# Error compiling PHP extensions - phpize (Ubuntu 14.04 + PHP 5.5)

Tags: php, extension

I'm trying to install the Paradox PHP extension to a Ubuntu Server 14.04.

The easy solution may be:

```
pecl install paradox
```

But it fails with this error:

> Cannot find config.m4. Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

So I tried to generate the paradox.so manually:

```
 tar -xzvf paradox-1.4.3.tgz
 phpize
 ./configure
 make
```

Ending with error: `make: *** [paradox.lo] Error 1`
The complete output: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/171128/make_output.txt

Trying to do the same with odbtp module (http://odbtp.sourceforge.net/) and it ends with the same error :- ((((

Any idea? :-(

Comment: I doubt you will ever get a package written in 2007, presumably for a 2.6.xx kernel, to compile correctly in 2015, presumably using a 3.13.xx kernel.